# Validating the date field's using angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using the angularJS for validation purpose in my project and i know to validate the normal fields. Now, i have the date field by the parameter passing in the name attribute. In some cases user can click the 'Add Date' button for adding more dates. So, in this case i have written the code by passing the parameter with the name attribute. Because of that i couldn't get the name field to validate.

Even if user add more date fields to enter i want to validate the all date fields.

Here is my code i am using,

```
 <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 table-responsive">
 <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <tr ng-repeat="dates in hall.hallDates">
       <td>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 p-0 p-t-10">
            Select Date<span style="color: red">*</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 p-0 p-t-10">
            <input type="text" ng-model="dates.hallDate"
                name="hallDate{{ $index }}" class="form-control"
                placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" mydatepicker readonly="true" 
                ng-class="{ validateFields: submitted && createHallForm.date.$invalid }" 
                required>
                <div ng-show="submitted && createHallForm.date.$invalid">
                    <span class="validateFields" ng-show="createHallForm.date.$error.required" >Please enter the date</span>
                </div>  
</div>
```

How to get the name field with parameter to apply validation for n number of fields?
Can anyone help me to know about this?

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using?

Comment: @Will M version is 1.2.10

Comment: Any chance you could upgrade your app to 1.3.x? 1.3 allows for dynamic name attributes so you can publish the errors.

Comment: @Will M Just i want to get the name field to validate. What's the problem in version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that you're running Angular 1.2 or below. In those versions you cannot dynamically set the `name` attribute of an element. You can confirm this by looking in the rendered DOM and still seeing 
`name="hallDate{{ $index }}"` after render.

See the related GitHub issue here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1404

**Solution 1**
Upgrade to 1.3.x

**Solution 2**
Use the following workaround as posted in the GitHub issue referenced above.

```
// Your app module
angular.module('app', [])

// Workaround for bug #1404
// https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1404
// Source: http://plnkr.co/edit/hSMzWC?p=preview
.config(['$provide', function($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('ngModelDirective', ['$delegate', function($delegate) {
    var ngModel = $delegate[0], controller = ngModel.controller;
    ngModel.controller = ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', '$injector', function(scope, element, attrs, $injector) {
      var $interpolate = $injector.get('$interpolate');
      attrs.$set('name', $interpolate(attrs.name || '')(scope));
      $injector.invoke(controller, this, {
        '$scope': scope,
        '$element': element,
        '$attrs': attrs
      });
    }];
    return $delegate;
  }]);
  $provide.decorator('formDirective', ['$delegate', function($delegate) {
    var form = $delegate[0], controller = form.controller;
    form.controller = ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', '$injector', function(scope, element, attrs, $injector) {
      var $interpolate = $injector.get('$interpolate');
      attrs.$set('name', $interpolate(attrs.name || attrs.ngForm || '')(scope));
      $injector.invoke(controller, this, {
        '$scope': scope,
        '$element': element,
        '$attrs': attrs
      });
    }];
    return $delegate;
  }]);
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks. I had upgraded the version and now it's working perfectly.